# Look up how many Panels have been created since last time proc was run

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to try and dynamically return how many Panels have be created since last time  the proc runs and return those newly created panels lot number.  I think we run the proc every minute. I play around with

```
  ---,datediff(mi,0,STOALL.CREDATTIM_0) +1
  --,STOALL.CREDATTIM_0
  --,rows=count(1)
```

but I think I am missing a peace. Any suggestions would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    STOALL.VCRNUM_0,
    STOCK.LOT_0,
    STOALL.CREDAT_0,
    STOALL.CREDATTIM_0
FROM 
    SANDBOX.MFGITM -- Finished good on work order
INNER JOIN 
    SANDBOX.MFGMAT ON MFGITM.MFGNUM_0 = MFGMAT.MFGNUM_0 -- Finished good materials
                   AND MFGITM.MFGLIN_0 = MFGMAT.MFGLIN_0
INNER JOIN 
    SANDBOX.MFGHEAD ON MFGITM.MFGNUM_0 = MFGHEAD.MFGNUM_0 -- Work order header
LEFT JOIN 
    SANDBOX.STOALL ON MFGMAT.MFGLIN_0 = STOALL.VCRLIN_0   -- Allocations
                   AND STOALL.VCRNUM_0 = MFGMAT.MFGNUM_0
LEFT JOIN 
    SANDBOX.STOCK ON STOALL.STOCOU_0 = STOCK.STOCOU_0       -- Stock
LEFT JOIN 
    SANDBOX.SORDERP ON SORDERP.SOHNUM_0 = MFGITM.VCRNUMORI_0    -- Sales order line price
                    AND SORDERP.SOPLIN_0 = MFGITM.VCRLINORI_0
LEFT JOIN 
    SANDBOX.SORDERQ ON SORDERQ.SOHNUM_0 = SORDERP.SOHNUM_0     -- Sales order line quantity
                    AND SORDERQ.SOPLIN_0 = SORDERP.SOPLIN_0
LEFT JOIN 
    SANDBOX.SORDER ON SORDERQ.SOHNUM_0 = SORDER.SOHNUM_0      -- Sales order header
LEFT JOIN 
    SANDBOX.ITMMASTER ON SANDBOX.MFGMAT.ITMREF_0 = SANDBOX.ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0
WHERE 
    ZSOSELECTED_0 = 2          -- Sales order header selection flag
    AND YSELECTED_0 = 0        -- Work order header selection flag
    AND ZBPSELECTION_0 = 2     -- Sales line selection flag
    AND SANDBOX.ITMMASTER.TSICOD_0 = 'HOP01'
    AND MFGHEAD.MFGSTA_0 <> 4
    -- AND MFGHEAD.MFGNUM_0 = 'WO111-181413'
    -- AND SANDBOX.STOALL.ALLTYP_0=2 --- flagged as allocation 
    -- AND VCRNUMORI_0='SC111-180481'
```

Comment: Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.